# Ionic capacitor Facebook login problem creating the facebook app step

Tags: firebase, facebook, ionic-framework, facebook-login, capacitor

I'm trying to add the Facebook login on my Ionic Capacitor Firebase app but i'm having a lot of problems creating the app on facebook developers site and associating it with my app, now i'm trying only with Android platform.

The problem is that it seems that to create the facebook app is mandatory to have the app published on store, because when i try to change public_profile access for example to advanced, is showing a modal saying that is not finding on the play store the app name. But I can't believe that is necessary to have the app on play store before integrate the facebook login on my app.

What i'm doing wrong? I'm following this tutorial https://devdactic.com/ionic-facebook-login-capacitor/ but on the video is not adding a store option on Android, and in my case i need to add google play or some other to save the platform.

I'm completely lost.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook should allow you to create an app in developer mode without necessarily entering the store code.

[image: app in development state]